# Fatal error from time to time while processing html with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom

I am extracting some meta data from Ikea site basing on catalogue number using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

number 30275861 and dozens other that I tested work properly and as result give that link ($produkt variable) and some data http://www.ikea.com/pl/pl/catalog/products/30275861/?query=30275861 (if link is pasted to browser it gives page with kallax system furniture)

giving number 69136138 - link result ($produkt variable) http://www.ikea.com/pl/pl/catalog/products/S69136138/?query=69136138 that works if pasted to browser (besta tv furniture) gives error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean

Code that works in most cases looks like this:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
function clean($string) {
$string = str_replace(',', '.', $string); 
return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-.]/', '', $string); 
}

if(isset($_POST['produkt_id'])){

$produkt_id=str_replace('.', '', $_POST['produkt_id']);

    $url="http://www.ikea.com/pl/pl/search/?query=".$produkt_id;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $a = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

    $url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // Return the last effective URL
    $produkt=(string)$url;

$html = file_get_html($produkt);

echo $produkt_id;
echo "<br>";
echo $produkt;

foreach($html->find('meta[name=partnumber]') as $e) echo $kod=$e->content;
foreach($html->find('link[rel=image_src"]') as $e) echo $obrazek=$e->href;      
foreach($html->find('meta[name=title]') as $e) echo $nazwa=$e->content; 
foreach($html->find('meta[name=price]') as $e) echo $cena=floatval(clean($e->content)); 
?>
```

Comment: what is `file_get_html`?

Comment: @Dekel  `file_get_html` is a  method of the `simple_html_dom` Class... ;-)

Comment: Since it's not standard PHP class/method you should mention it in your post (link to the lib should be provided).

Comment: [..]using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. and in code include('simple_html_dom.php'); But You are right here is the link http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Why not try wrapping your `foreach` loops in conditional statement so that the loops would only run if `$html` is neither null nor empty?

```
    <?php

         // ... SOME CODE ABOVE            
         $html = file_get_html($produkt);

        /* WHY NOT (AT THIS POINT) TRY TO INSPECT THE CONTENT OF $html? WITH VAR_DUMP?*/
        var_dump($html);       //<== JUST TO SEE THE DATA CONTENT...

        // ONLY RUN FOR LOOPS (ECHOING OUT SOME DATA)
        // IF AND ONLY IF $html HAS SOME CONTENT     
        if($html && !empty($html)){
            echo $produkt_id;  //<== MAKES SENSE TO ECHO THIS ONLY IF $html HAS DATA
            echo "<br>";       //<== MAKES SENSE TO ECHO THIS ONLY IF $html HAS DATA
            echo $produkt;     //<== MAKES SENSE TO ECHO THIS ONLY IF $html HAS DATA

            foreach($html->find('meta[name=partnumber]') as $e){
                echo $kod=$e->content;
            }
            foreach($html->find('link[rel=image_src"]') as $e){
                echo $obrazek=$e->href;   
            } 
            foreach($html->find('meta[name=title]') as $e){
                echo $nazwa=$e->content; 
            }
            foreach($html->find('meta[name= price]') as $e){
                echo $cena=floatval(clean($e->content)); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Poiz. Indeed code is dirty and not optimal but that's not the point - is there anyone able to tell me WHY both links target the same page but one works as source of data another not - that's the question here.